# Changing multiple radio buttons selection based upon one radio checked in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and stuck at a situation where i want to bind the selected radio option to model/controller object. what i am trying to do is, All three radio buttons(A, B and C) should show same option which is choosen in App1 radio options, later each(A, B and C radio button options) can be changed depending on the usecase, i want to save the clicks for user.

For example: if a user chooses Y option in App1 set of radio buttons then all the three A B and C radio button option with Y option should be checked.

Any help is much appreciated.`Plunk here`https://plnkr.co/edit/vuLJdUFSTsUp5hfoazBp?p=preview

Comment: plunker is not working and need more clarity on the question

Comment: @SrikanthB edited the question and plunker is working now

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of index provided by angular. Here is the code how I do

html code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
<div ng-repeat="app in apps" ng-init="index1 = $index">
    {{app.proj}}
    <span ng-repeat="tc in typeCodes" ng-init="index2 = $index">
        <input type="radio" name="app_{{index1}}" ng-model="app.selectedCode" value={{tc.key}} 
               ng-change="selectionChanged(index1, app.selectedCode)">{{tc.key}}
    </span>
    <div>
        <span ng-repeat="subApp in app.subApps" ng-init="index3 = $index">
            {{subApp.appName}}-
            <span ng-repeat="tc in typeCodes" ng-init="index4 = $index">
                <input type="radio" name="tc_{{index1}}_{{index3}}" ng-model="subApp.type" ng-value="{{tc.key}}" 
                       ng-checked="subApp.type === tc.key"
                       ng-change="subAppSelection(index1, index3, tc.key)">{{tc.key}}
            </span><br>
        </span>
    </div><br><br>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.selectionChanged = function (ind, type) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.apps[ind].subApps.length; j++) {
        $scope.apps[ind].subApps[j].type = type;
    }
}

$scope.subAppSelection = function (ind1, ind2, type) {
    $scope.apps[ind1].subApps[ind2].type = type;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for spending time on this, works like a charm, but one more thing to add for the current flow. While reading the apps object > subApp > type property, can i assign it a code for every subApp? so that particular radio button will pre-populate once the page loads. I've tried updating the type property a code to Y/N/M but only one radio button is pre-populating for an object(App1). Updated the plunker